# Xamarin.Forms iOS + Android support for native link auto-detection

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, custom-renderer

I am struggling to find the cross-platform answer to native link detection in labels. In Android, it seems to be [TextView's AutoLink](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:autoLink), which is set up in my custom renderer subclass of LabelRenderer. But in iOS, you have to do it through [UITextView's dataDetectorTypes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatadetectortypes) which is the Xam.Forms equivalent of an Entry/Editor. So how do I make a Label-esque View in XF such that on Android it uses LabelRenderer but on iOS it uses EditorRenderer (multi-line support is necessary). I started to subclass a XF View and write custom bindings that would wire up to either a XF Editor on iOS or a XF Label on Android, but that just started to feel wrong.

Then I tried to just subclass Editor for both, but my attempts to make that look/behave like a static Label on Android were a mess (this has to work as a ListView DataTemplate and one thing I found odd was that it was confusing HasUnevenRows height when the ListViewCachingStrategy was set to Recycle).

I also started to do custom ViewRenderers per platform but that seemed like a total mess because you basically don't get to inherit any of the goodness that comes with LabelRenderer / EditorRenderer and you're forced to recreate it all... which I wasn't getting good results with either.

It seems like there should be an easy way in XF to support each platforms' native link detection in a single View?

Comment: Nope, Xamarin forms do not provide this feature, you should achieve it by custom renderer. https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/tag/xamarin-hyperlink-label/

Comment: Thanks @LeonLu-MSFT , great work! This was one of the approaches I tried, but when doing it this way you lose all the LabelRenderer magic that Xamarin Forms has already done. I was finding myself having to reimplement the entire thing, but there were still rendering issues for my application (these are used within a DataTemplate of a ListView so I think that had something to do with it). I'll take a closer look at your code to see if it will help!

Comment: Do you have some update?